# I can't make media queries for height one div

Tags: html, css

I 've couple divs in my project, when I add media queries with new div's height to css style sheet it's won't work when I open it on firefox responsive mode. I'm already frustrated because different queries working but height won't cooperate.

html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

css:

```
.div2-area{
 background-color: grey;
 width: 100%;
 height: 200vh;
 font-family: 'Palatino Linotype';
 text-align: left;
 color: white;
 background-position: center center;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-image: url(../images/33.jpg);
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .div2-area {
    height: 450vh;
  }
}
```

Comment: It happens to me sometimes and I fix it with important, try it this way:
height: 450vh !important;

Comment: those it happening only on firefox or other browser also

Comment: It won't help. May on the phone it will by okey

Comment: @CormoranMichael you mean its not taking the height:450vh?

Comment: Yes, it not taking the height:450vh.

Comment: for me its working on chromium and firefox so plz explain what you want and why on 300 px ?

Comment: I want to height to this div increse to 450vh when width of device/ window is smaller then 300px

Comment: yeas it working ive tested it on chromium and firefox

Comment: Thats work now. I've no idea why it doesn't work. Thanks guys